# What is "strComputer"?

Tags: vbscript

I've had to do a little VBScript recently, and many scripts that I've seen use this variable `strComputer` which, on the surface anyway, seems pointless. It's typically set to `"."`, and then used in a string concatenation like so:

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
```

Why is this done, when one could simply write `Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")`? I see this all over the place and it mystifies me.

Comment: Well, you could make it point to a different computer; it just makes the configurability more obvious.

Comment: Someone at MS used this in sample code and everyone copied. It can be any computername. If `.` it means the local computer. Eg: from WMI docs `strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
    & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @false pointed out in the comments to the question, the purpose is to make the computer whose WMI service you want to access configurable.

`.` is a shortcut for the local computer. If you're certain that your script will only ever be connecting to the local computer there is indeed no benefit to be gained from a configurable computername, and you're better off just merging the `.` into the moniker:

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
```

However, if you need the ability to run the script against remote hosts, you can for instance make the host configurable via a commandline argument:

```
strComputer = "."   'default to localhost

If WScript.Arguments.Exists("ComputerName") Then
  strComputer = WScript.Arguments.Named("ComputerName")
End If

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

'do stuff with objWMIService
```

or read a list of hostnames from a file:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\computerlist.txt")

Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
  strComputer = f.ReadLine
  Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

  'do stuff with objWMIService
Loop

f.Close
```