# Check for running process on multiple machines

Tags: vbscript

I am new to VBS, but was able to create a simple script to determine if PowerPoint is running on my local machine. My ultimate goal, however, is to check multiple remote machines, and display results such as:
Machine1:Not running
Machine2:Running
Machine3:Not running
and so on.

And that's where I get stuck.

```
Dim i
Dim strComputer
Dim FindProc

strComputer = "."

FindProc = "powerpnt"

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select Name from Win32_Process WHERE Name LIKE '" & FindProc & "%'")

If colProcessList.count>0 then
wscript.echo "Powerpoint is running"
else
wscript.echo "Powerpoint is not running"
End if

Set objWMIService = Nothing
Set colProcessList = Nothing
```

Comment: What is your issue exactly?

Comment: Getting the code to check multiple remote machines, and display the status for each

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

Regarding the output, you can always write it to a file in a fashion that suits your needs or build a string of the desired format by concatenating each machine status during each iteration and `Wscript.Echo` it afterwards. It may be failing to find the process due to a variety of reasons (e.g. the string you are using for referencing the target computer is incorrectly formatted), I really can't tell for sure without more context. I have rewritten the solution trying to keep it as clear and similar as possible to your own code.

```
Dim FSObject, MachineListObject, outFileObject
Dim processName, objWMIService, coolProcesses, strComputer

Set FSObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set MachineListObject = FSObject.OpenTextFile("C:\test\remote_hosts.txt") 
Set outFileObject = FSObject.CreateTextFile("C:\test\out.txt", True)

processName = "notepad++.exe" 'Change this to your process of choice

Do While Not MachineListObject.AtEndOfStream

    strComputer =  MachineListObject.ReadLine()
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

    Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = '" & processName & "'")

    If colProcesses.Count <> 0  then
        outFileObject.Write "Machine " & strComputer & ": Service is running" & vbCrLf
    Else
        outFileObject.Write "Machine " & strComputer & ": Service is not running" & vbCrLf  
    End If

Loop

outFileObject.Close
```

These might help you: [What is "strComputer"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24393774/what-is-strcomputer) and [Win32_Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/CIMWin32Prov/win32-process) (scroll down to the examples section in case you just want to get it working asap)

Comment: That gets me closer. So a couple of things:
1. It is not checking the process correctly. I put my local machine in the text file, opened PowerPoint, and ran the script, however, it tells me it's not running

2. Is there another way of displaying the results? I would like all of the status to appear at one time, like:

     Machine1:Service Not running
     Machine2:Service Running
     Machine3:Service Running

Comment: I edited my answer, check the thread I linked and see if you can have any success now.